# Removing HTML tags from Postgres text/xml, with exceptions?

Tags: xml, postgresql, wysiwyg, regexp-replace

I am working with a frontend that utilizes a wysiwyg editor, and we want to be able to support specific html tags in the string input (`i`, `strong`, `p`, `h1` tags, etc).

The frontend makes serverless queries directly to a Postgres db.

There seem to be ways to remove all HTML tags from a string/xml by utilizing `regexp_replace`; but is there a way to utilize a Postgres trigger/function to remove HTML tags with a set of explicit exceptions?

I am looking for functionality similar to pHp's `strip_tags` method, but I have not been able to find guidance for this use case.

TIA!

Comment: can you exlain how html tags are stored in postgres, and provide a concrete example of html tags to be removed except a set of explicit exceptions ?

Comment: @Edouard it is being stored in a single varchar, or xml. The html tags to be removed, for this example, are any tags that are not `i`, `strong`, `p`, or `h1`; so we want to remove anything with `script`, `DOCTYPE`, `meta`, etc.